# How do I actually send an email from python code?

Tags: python, email

The email package provide the following code:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Open the plain text file whose name is in textfile for reading.
with open(textfile) as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(fp.read())

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {textfile}'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

I made minimal modifications to try to send myself an 'hello world' email:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content("Hello")

msg['Subject'] = 'test mail'
msg['From'] = 'personnal.mail@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'personnal.mail@gmail.com'

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

(where the mail has been anonymised)

I get the following error:

```
[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Can someone indicates what step should be taken to make this work?

Comment: I suggest you post the stack trace of your exception.

Comment: You need an SMTP server. You're using a GMAIL account with an SMTP localhost server. User smtp.gmail.com on ports 25, 465 or 587. You'll probabily need to login or generate an auth token

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that, sending an email needs a server that manages the communication. It's called SMTP server.

With a gmail account you need to use Google's SMTP server.

Below and example on how to use it

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

subject = 'test mail'
body = 'Hello'
sender = 'personnal.mail@gmail.com'
recipient = 'personnal.mail@gmail.com'
password = "your_gmail_password"


def send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients, password):
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = recipient 
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
       smtp_server.login(sender, password)
       smtp_server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
    print("Message sent!")


send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients, password)
```

The code

```
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
           smtp_server.login(sender, password)
           smtp_server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

actually login and use the Google's SMTP server to send your email

Comment: SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i6-20020a17090332c600b001db594c9d17sm9135787plr.254 - gsmtp') is the error I get

Comment: @LucasMorin are you using 2FA? You may need to create a token and use it as password. Btw the error literally tells you what's wrong and how to fix it

Comment: No 2FA on my account (and I can't find the 'allow less secured app' that seems to be mentioned everywhere)

Comment: @LucasMorin it's been deprecated https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en you must use oauth. This could be helpful https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: It is not clear from the link you provide what steps should be taken.

Comment: @LucasMorin from what I'm understanding, because the new Google security policy, you're unable to use Google SMTP server with Python and the `smtplib`. You're forced to use Google's API and Oauth